# How to append the osgi.configuration.area parameter to the generated config.ini in Eclipse 3.8.2?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I am desperately trying to configure my Eclipse product to fulfill the advices to achieve an Eclipse Multiuser Install (according to this [document](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html)). I am following #2 and #3 by specifying a

```
osgi.instance.area=@user.home/.<productname>
```

as well as:

```
osgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.<productname>/configuration
```

The actual problem is, that the key `osgi.configuration.area` appears nowhere and therefore the wrong directory will be chosen to write internal osgi fileLocks.
I would have expected it in the generated

> *product_location*/configuration/config.ini

file by the `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser` in my build artefact.

I placed the arguments in the "Properties"-section of the "Configuration" tab of the product-editor.

According to the timestamp it seems this `config.ini` is created during the build process, but I am not sure. Does somebody know when this `EquinoxConfigFileParser` is activated and from where it obtains the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally do this by configuring the `ProductName.ini` file in your application root directory.
For example:

```
-data
@user.home/AppData/Roaming/PRODUCT/workspace
-configuration
@user.home/AppData/Roaming/PRODUCT/configuration
```

According to the [eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html):

- `osgi.instance.area` is equivalent to `-data`
- `osgi.configuration.area` is equivalent to `-configuration`

You can specify those arguments in your `.product` file. Switch to the "Launching" tab, insert into the "Program Arguments" field.

Comment: Great.But isn't that <product>.ini generated as well? As I see it, it contains also "-startup" followed by org.eclipse.launcher_version_buildversion.jar, which is dynamic.

Comment: Yes it is generated as well, you can specify the arguments in the "Launching" tab, in the "Program Arguments" field.

Comment: As I recall it, we had problems with configuring the `configurations/config.ini` parameters that's why we switched to the `ProductName.ini` options.

Comment: When adding these key/values to the launching parameters, the product won't start when being launched from within Eclipse. Haven't found out the reason so far, but something with -product/-feature seems to be disabled implicitly. Its a tough one.

Comment: Does it launch as a product? The workspace and configurations location from an eclipse launch is managed in the "Main" tab "Workspace Data" and in the "Configurations" tab "Configuration Area".

Comment: Yes, it does. That's how we debug the application. I will provide a Launch-Configuration to handle the parameters separately from the product definition. Good hint. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I did exactly what you proposed. A launch config enables developers to start the product from within Eclipse. But *sigh* the new Program Arguments (data, config) are not be found in the final build artefact. Which brings me to the conclusion to check the build. Even though I thought the product definition is the template for the build artefact.

Comment: As mentioned the parameters are handled separately for product and launch. If you add the parameters in your `.product` file ("Launching" tab,  "Program Arguments"), they should end up in your root `.ini` file `Application/Application.ini`.